# go test is failing because of root path changed

Tags: go, filepath

I am running `go test -v $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)` to run all tests excluding vendor. 
My file structure is

```
myRepo
  api
    user_test.go
  config
    key.json
  main.go
```

I have key.json file under config folder for maintianing all api keys.
I am using [filepath.Abs](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Abs) to load key.json file. Everything is working fine except when I run tests. When I run go tests the root path is changing to myRepo/api and the error I am getting is unable to find myRepo/api/config/key.json

Comment: by "root path" do you mean your working directory? Using `filepath.Abs` doesn't do any good if you're relying on giving it a relative path. Test files need to be inside the package being tested, or you need to search via absolute paths to begin with.

Comment: Yes root path means working directory in the terms I used above. yes I am putting test files inside the package that  I want to test. I have searched a lot for 3 days. I did not find soultion to this and asked here. Hope someone will help me.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] which we can see the exact problem. If your config data is in the package, then it will be there for the tests (there's a reason why the name `testdata` is ignored by the go tools, since it often resides in the package itself)

Comment: Here you go. I have created a GitHub repo [golang-test](https://github.com/RTBathula/golang-test) with minimal code to create problem that I am facing. Please help me

Comment: `config/` is not in the package that's looking for it, so you can't rely on a relative path to find it. You need to either put the test data in the package being tested, or make a way to find the data without a relative path.

Comment: Could you give me an example or create a GitHub repo?

Comment: If you want some data to be included in a package's test, you need to put the data _inside_ that package, otherwise you have to search for it via an absolute path. You could look for the package source using $GOPATH as a starting point. Note that you can't reliably deploy an application like this either, since the location of the source has nothing to do with the location of the deployed binary.